# How to read several csv files into a HashMap?

Tags: java, spring

I have 3 different types of csv files, each with different headers. I currently use a `MultiresourceItemReader` and delegate the reading to a `FlatfileItemReader` as follows

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public MultiResourceItemReader<Model> multiResourceItemReader() {
        MultiResourceItemReader<FileRow> resourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<FileRow>();
        resourceItemReader.setResources( getInputResources() );
        resourceItemReader.setDelegate( reader() );
        return resourceItemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader reader() {
        log.debug("Header : {}", extraInfoHolder.getHeader());
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Model>()
                .skippedLinesCallback(line -> {
                    String rsrc = multiResourceItemReader().getCurrentResource().toString();
                    log.debug("Current Resource : {}", rsrc);

                    // Verify file header is what we expect
                    if (!StringUtils.equals( line, extraInfoHolder.getHeader() )) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException( String.format("Invalid Header in " + rsrc) );
                    }
                })
                .name( "myReader" )
                .linesToSkip( HEADER_ROW )
                .lineMapper( new DefaultLineMapper() {
                    {
                        setLineTokenizer( getDelimitedLineTokenizer() );
                        setFieldSetMapper( getBeanWrapperFieldSetMapper() );
                    }} )
                .build();
    }
```

However, I'd like to read the csv file into an HashMap instead of a Model POJO, i.e. if the file is formatted as follows 
 
`First Name, Last Name, Age`
 `Doug, Jones, 57` 
 `Sam, Reed, 39`
 
I'd like to read each line into a map where the key is the header token and the value is the file value, 
 
 Map 1: 
 `First Name -> Doug` 
 `Last Name -> Jones` 
 `Age -> 57`

 Map 2: 
 `First Name -> Sam` 
 `Last Name -> Reed` 
 `Age -> 39`

In classic Spring Batch fashion, I'd like to read one row, convert it into a map, process + write it, then read the next row. How can I achieve this?

Comment: So you're going to create n-1 maps for n lines in a csv file? Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: Yes, the way the standard file reader-processor-writer works is by creating an object for each row of the file anyway. So I'd be replacing n-1 objects with n-1 maps. It's largely because of the flexibility maps offer

Comment: But you will have n-1 maps with **size equal to one**. This does not offer you any flexibility because there is only one entry to query. So a list with one element would no longer be different from an array of one element or a stack with one element, etc... Wouldn't be more appropriate to use one `Map<Person,Integer>`?

Comment: The size will be equal to the number of header tokens. In my example, each map will be of size 3.

Comment: You're right but again why not implement a `Map<Person,Integer>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the maps that you want,

```
private static List<Map<String, Object>> getMapsFrom(String file) throws IOException {
 List<Map<String, Object>> maps = new ArrayList<>();
   try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(file))))) {
            int index = 0;
            String line;
            String[] keys = new String[3];

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (index++ == 0){
                    keys = line.split(",");
                }else{
                    String[] values = line.split(",");
                    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                        values[i] = values[i].trim();
                    }
                    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put(keys[0], values[0]);
                    map.put(keys[1], values[1]);
                    map.put(keys[2], Integer.parseInt(values[2]));
                    maps.add(map);
                }
            }
        }
        return maps;
    }
```

assuming your csv file is always in the form of

```
First Name, Last Name, Age
Doug, Jones, 57
Sam, Reed, 39
```

Here is a screenshot of the maps returned from the file sample above,

[image]